# PHP get all unclosed HTML tags in string

Tags: php, html, tags

How can I get all the unclosed tags in a given string, prefferably in the order they should be closed?

Note: consider that there are no errors in the HTML and that it was just cut off after X characters. No it's not a case of bad html or overlapping tags etc. Also there will be no ending

Example:
`<p><span>Lorem</span><b>ipsum`  ---return--->  `</b></p>`

-OR-
`<ul><li>1</li><li>2`  ---return--->  `</li></ul>`

So that if the string is concatenated with the function output it will re-create a valid HTML.

I'm not sure if a RegExp would do the trick here, basically I want to get anything that's between < and > that does not have a matching </ > closing tag.

Thank you.

Comment: What about an `<img>` tag that's unclosed? Do you care about that? (I realize it won't work with the close function you have, but you might get close tags that aren't used, such as `</img>`.)

Comment: Hey. The current algorithm makes sure truncation does not happen in the middle of a tag and `<img>` tags are ended with `<img/>`. So that's not a problem in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an easy task. You might want to look at [Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/):

> Tidy is a binding for the Tidy HTML
>   clean and repair utility which allows
>   you to not only clean and otherwise
>   manipulate HTML documents, but also
>   traverse the document tree.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php