# Match unclosed html tags using regex and php

Tags: php, regex

I am using php and regex to find  unclosed html tags in a string :

This is my string :

```
$s="<div><h2>Hello world<h2><p>It's 7Am where I live<p><div>";
```

You can see All tags here are not closed.

I want to find all unclosed tags, but the problem is that my regex is matching opening tags also.

Here is my regex so far

```
/<[^>]+>/i
```

And this is my preg_match_all() function

```
preg_match_all("/<[^>]+>/i",$s,$v);

print_r($v);
```

What do I need to change in my regex to match only the unclosed tags?

```
 <h2>
 <p>
 <div>
```

Comment: you should look into `tidy` http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Comment: Self developed solution for educational purpose: Build a tokenizer that basically identifies tags (opening and closing) and any other text fragments. Iterate the tokens with a stack holding the opened tags. If you encounter an opening tag, put it on the stack. If you encounter a closing tag, check if the counterpart is on the top of the stack: if they match, remove it from the stack; if not, react accordingly (e. g., throwing an error or discarding the encountered closing tag).

Comment: This is not what regex is for.

Comment: @Starkeen: I agree with Brandin, it is too difficult to solve with just regex replacements, and I believe you already wasted much time on that. If my answer does not help with specific input, please post those samples and I will be glad to help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might be unaware of this, but `DOMDocument` can help you fix the HTML.

```
$html = "<div><h2>Hello world<h2><p>It's 7Am where I live<p><div>";
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<root>' . $html . '</root>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach( $xpath->query('//*[not(node())]') as $node ) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo substr($dom->saveHTML(), 6, -8);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/WnUzVh)

Result: `<div><h2>Hello world</h2><p>It's 7Am where I live</p></div>`

Note that the XPath-based empty node cleanup is necessary as the DOM contains empty `<h2></h2>`, `<p></p>` and `<div></div>` tags after loading HTML into DOM.

The `<root>` element is added in the beginning to make sure we get the root element alright. Later, we can post-process it with `substr`.

The `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` flags are necessary so that no DTD and other rubbish were not added to the DOM.

Comment: Lovin' your opening line btw. Yet, an ideone "stickler"; so many times I've seen answers containing a link to it, only to find out that they're blank as a year or so goes on. Just a quick sidenote about that. When Googling stuff for Q&A's, I find answers often with those blank ideone URLs (a few this week actually). As to why that is, I don't know. *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes, unfortunately, they are deleted when not visited. However, I provide full code in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Finding unmatched tags seems fundamentally too hard to do with a regex.  You basically need to put each opening tag to you see onto a queue and then pop it off of the queue when you see the closing tag.

Recommend you use a library that does HTML validation.  See these questions:

[Remove unmatched HTML tags in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580186/remove-unmatched-html-tags-in-a-string)

[How to find the unclosed div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272327/how-to-find-the-unclosed-div-tag)

[PHP get all unclosed HTML tags in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822156/php-get-all-unclosed-html-tags-in-string)