# Regex to match Tags NOT surrounded by Tags

Tags: php, regex

I have the following example:

```
<p>skljklf askjas</p>
<li>dsjd sjg</li> <li>skdkgds</li>
<li>skask las</li>
<p>skklgs aklgas</p>
<ul><li>saks </li><li>isksa</li></ul>
<li>asjkafsklj  asjlkafs</li>
```

As you can see there are `li`-tags which are not surrounded by an `ul`. I am trying to find a regex which selects **all** occurences of `<li>...</li><li>...</li>` and surrounds them with `<ul></ul>`. So at the end I would have the following text:

```
<p>skljklf askjas</p>
<ul><li>dsjd sjg</li> <li>skdkgds</li>
<li>skask las</li></ul>
<p>skklgs aklgas</p>
<ul><li>saks </li><li>isksa</li></ul>
<ul><li>asjkafsklj  asjlkafs</li></ul>
```

Trying it in php with `preg_replace` and `mb_ereg_replace`, but no real clue yet how I could start.

I don't want to do DOM manipulation with `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Related  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903256/match-unclosed-html-tags-using-regex-and-php ?

Comment: @starkeen tim007 already found a solution with regex

Comment: regex is the wrong tool for the job, and using regex to parse HTML will only postpone and amplify your suffering.

Comment: @zzzzBov I know. But I need this temporary and fast solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<!<ul>)(?<!<\/li>)((?:\s*\n*<li>[^<]*<\/li>\s*\n*)+)(?<!<li>)(?!<\/ul>)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qM9yO6/1)

```
$re = "/(?<!<ul>)(?<!<\\/li>)((?:<li>[^<]*<\\/li>\\s*\\n*)+)(?<!<li>)(?!<\\/ul>)/"; 
$str = "<p>skljklf askjas</p>\n<li>dsjd sjg</li> <li>skdkgds</li>\n<li>skask las</li>\n<p>skklgs aklgas</p>\n<ul><li>saks </li><li>isksa</li></ul>\n<li>asjkafsklj  asjlkafs</li>"; 
$str = preg_replace($re, '<ul>$0</ul>', $str);
```

Comment: sadly it matches one thing too much: "<ul>    <li>asd</li><li>aasdfgh</li>  </ul>" :/