# How to find all unopened div tags across an entire site?

Tags: html, string, tags, find, dreamweaver

so I've been tasked with doing an update for an existing website.

The problem lies in the fact that there are unopened div tags (`</div>` with no `<div>` before it.) appearing at least a few times on almost every page. There are over 470 pages....

It'd look something like this:

```
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Layer Slider -->
  </div> **This is useless**
  </div> **This is useless**
  <div class="bottom_shadow"></div>
  </div> **This is useless**
</section>
```

The update that I need to do involves putting a div container around the content and affects every page which gets messed up by these random `</div>`s. Is there any way to find these without having to check every single page? I'm using Dreamweaver 2020.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: post an example please

Comment: I had them included in the post, I don't know what happened. One second.

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903256/match-unclosed-html-tags-using-regex-and-php for an automated approach, otherwise this https://validator.w3.org/ or this might also be useful https://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/

Comment: From my quick look into using TIDY, it appears that it would only be able to find unclosed tages, as opposed to unopened tags, same with aliciamirez's tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about if there is any tool. If your code is pure HTML, you can use W3C validator and also it shows unopened tags with line numbers. The problem is you need to check every page.

Please check
[W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: They're actually php files unfortunately, and I'd really like to avoid checking every page by hand.